# Microsoft Dynamics AX Versions for various Operating Systems

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I want to know what AX version will be install with which Operating System version like, can I install AX 2012 with Windows Server 2008?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11094

> Windows Server 2008 Standard Edition, Enterprise Edition, Web Edition,
>   or Datacenter Edition, with Service Pack 2 Only 64-bit versions of
>   Windows Server 2008 are supported.

So to answer your question... Yes, you'll be able to install AX 2012 on Server 2008 with SP2 and 64 bit version.